# Problems with reading from a file in java, .txt file always erases

Tags: java

I'm taking a Grade 11 course in Java right now, and thus I am new to programming in Java. My assignment is to ask the user their name and a password, put their password on a .txt (the .txt file's name would be the name they input), and ask if they've played before (that's for the second half of the assignment). If they enter 'no' it will ask them to input a password for the future. If they exit and run the program again and input 'yes' then it will prompt the user to input the password they put in when they said 'no'.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
class passwordtest
{
public static void main (String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String name, password, input, filepassword;

    System.out.println ("Please enter your name");
    name = br.readLine ();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (name + ".txt");

    System.out.println ("Have you played this game before?");
    input = br.readLine ();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("no"))
    {
        System.out.println ("Please enter a password that you can use for later.");
        password = br.readLine ();
        fw.write (password);
        fw.close ();
    }

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("yes"))
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (name + ".txt");
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader (fr);
        filepassword = bfr.readLine ();

        System.out.println ("Please enter your password");
        password = br.readLine ();

        if (!password.equals (filepassword))
        {
            System.out.println ("Wrong password.");
        }
        if (password.equals (filepassword))
        {
            System.out.println ("Right password. Enjoy the program!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem here is that every time I run the program to say 'yes' the .txt file erases, thus making it impossible for me to be able to see if the user entered the correct password.
I've been struggling with this for the past couple of hours, please help.

Comment: Don't create the FileWriter until you know that you need to overwrite the file, i.e. until the user has entered "no". Just like you're already doing for the FileReader: you only create it oce you know the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (name + ".txt");
```

This is enough to create a new file.  Place it carefully.

Comment: Hm. what do you mean by place it carefully?

Comment: I mean think carefully about where this line of code belongs.  As you've figured out already, it doesn't belong where you put it.

Comment: Thank you, I put the line of code under the "no" part and it works now.

Comment: Excellent.  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if you found it helpful.